# 8 less than triple a number is equal to -5 (I'm trying to find the unknown number)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It's a hard question... for my thinking! I've tried many solutions but haven't figured it out. 
(Let $M$ be the unknown number)

I've tried:

$M^3-8=-5$

Then

$M^3-8+8=5+8$

Then I think the answer is
$M^3=13$

Comment: Triple a number is not the same as the number squared. Instead your equation should be $3M-8=-5$.

Comment: @ René B. Christensen: I think "cubed" is the word you are looking for.

Comment: @abstract Yes, of course. I might have written that comment a bit too  fast.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** A number is tripled if it is multiplied by $3$, not put to the third power. For example, tripling the number $5$ gives $15$.